# Drupal gives error to admin, anonymous users can browse pages

Tags: commerce

Anonymous users can browse various pages, when logged in, it gives "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later". I am using drupal 7 commerce. Before this error I installed drupal example modules and drupal commerce example modules.  THe image is attached which shows the errors. [image: unnexpected error ococcur]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the error message only prints when an admin is logged in, you can disable that by going to Administer > Site configuration > Error reporting, anyway you can still fix the problem, by rebuilding your permissions, it mostly can cause by enabling permission dependent modules, like content access or something else.

Comment: I don't think so, error reporting is on for both anony and admin. When I log in, the site gets stuck there and cannot go to any other page. (2) I've tried to rebuild the permissions but it cannot rebuild bcoz of these errors.